# Limit image file size download

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Sometimes I'm on limited data and thus would like to save as much as possible but still want to browse certain websites. Some of these websites may have high resolution PNG files on their homepages resulting in "wasted" bandwidth.

Is there a setting in either firefox or chrome that allows me to filter out images that are bigger than X bytes and just making those show their alt-text instead?

Comment: I'm never going to give you up!

Comment: Not reliably, no. Because a) not all webservers correctly announce the size of a file when transmitting it, and b) even for those that do, by the time you've received the file size you've also begun downloading the file already. You could abort after you've begun downloading if the filesize is beyond a certain threshold but by that time you've already wasted some (though little) data to find that out.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Exactly, I meant through content length, just for the webservers that do announce the correct size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet compression proxy for low speed broadband?](https://superuser.com/questions/254366/internet-compression-proxy-for-low-speed-broadband)

Comment: A number of direct solutions in the proposed duplicate, but here's an idea for a workaround.  There are add-ons that let you clean up a web page for printing.  Virtually every element, or group of elements, on the page is selectable and deletable.  They're designed to let you eliminate the parts you don't care about so the printout can be more compact.  On pages that might consume excessive bandwidth, eliminate the fluff and non-critical images, then save it as a PDF, which you download.  Some of these add-ons may also automatically reduce images to a reasonable resolution and compression.

Comment: In the old days there was an Opera Mobile client that piped access through a compression proxy Opera operated to reduce filesize of all images, I suspect those solutions and similar would be easier to achieve than the proposal in this question.